# How to run a jar file and launch terminal from java program?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I want to run jar file from my java program.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "parallel/Parallel.jar", "aug/*.xml");
Process p = pb.start();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String s = "";
while((s = in.readLine()) != null){
  System.out.println(s);
}
int status = p.waitFor();
System.out.println("Exited with status: " + status);
```

Here is the error log I get:

```
[33mProblem found trying to create the log file[0m
[31mCannot locate configuration source aug/*.xml[0m
[31mNo files to work with[0m
Exited with status: 1
```

Problem 1: I tried using a whole file name instead of the * and it works. But, I want to run the jar on ALL files under the directory.

Problem 2: When run, the jar file will ask for some input "continue" or "cancel". But the jar program just exits in the Eclipse console without giving me chance to input anything. So, I am wondering if there is a way to launch the jar file inside a terminal?

Comment: Please provide more details about what your JAR `parallel/Parallel.jar`. If this JAR requires inputs, you should use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream()

Comment: Are you sure it just exits in Eclipse (when you provide it with a valid file name) rather than waiting for input that never comes from the pipes?

Answer (score 0):

For 1. 
aug/*.xml does not work that way because the unfolding of the wildcard is done by cmd/bash. If you want to use it that way your jar would need to be able to unfold that string itself or you would have to call it using cmd/bash.
It would be preferable letting your java program Parallel unfold this so that you do not loose portability.

For 2. 
To run it from a terminal you could use ProcessBuilder or Runtime.exec() 
Something like that on windows: (windows cmd needs the path or it will not resolve your wildcard)

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /k start java -jar <path>/Parallel.jar <path>/aug/*.xml");
```

"/k" keeps the terminal active. "start" opens the terminal instead of just executing the command.

With ProcessBuilder it should be something like:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/k", "start", "java", "-jar", "<path>/Parallel.jar", "<path>/aug/*.xml");
```

For bash it would be along that lines:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("sh", "-c", "java", "-jar", "<path>/Parallel.jar", "<path>/aug/*.xml");
```

For further reading about Processbuilder/Runtime.exec() I would suggest: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html